# How to access Native database of existing Android project through React Native

Tags: android, sqlite, react-native, android-sqlite

I have an android application written in java and I have lots of data in the SQLite database also.
Now I want to integrate a module through react Native and existing database access is required in this module.
But I am unable to make a connection with the database.

```
enter code here
```

`` "dependencies": {`enter code here`
    "react": "~16.9.0",
    "react-native": "~0.61.4",
    "react-native-sqlite-storage": "^4.0.0"
  } ``

````
    SQLite.enablePromise(true);
    var db = SQLite.openDatabase({name : "mydb", location: 'default'})
    .then(res => {
      console.log(`Success ${res}`)
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log(`Error1 ${err}, ${err.code}`)
    });
  }```


getting error:
**TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'NativeModules["SQLite"][method]')**
````

Answer (score 0):

Question might be old, but in case anyone should have the same problem as the author and I had: What worked for me, was opening the project in Android Studio, cleaning it and rebuilding it. Then close Android Studio and work normally from command line etc.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing run-android to recompile.